# Условия для значения :checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, cookie

Доброго дня.
Мне нужна ваша помощь.

Задача такая, существует checkbox который при клике на него, отключает звук на сайте, (<аudiо>) и рабочий код такой:

```
$(function(){
    $("#mute").click(function () {
        if ($("#mute").is(":checked")) {
            $("#notify").prop('muted', true);
        } else {
            $("#notify").prop('muted', false);
        }
    });
});
```

(я уже создавал подобную тему, но вопрос теперь в другом) Код выше работает во идеи, осталось сохранить значение в куки ($.cookie), сохраняю так:

```
//сохраняю в куки
$(window).load(function(){
    var url = "/js/cookie.js";
    $.getScript(url, function() {
        $("input.settings").each(function() {
            var $cookie = $.cookie($(this).attr('name'));
            if ($cookie && $cookie == "true") {
                $(this).prop('checked', $cookie);
            }
        });
        $("input.settings").change(function() {
            $.cookie($(this).attr("name"), $(this).prop('checked'), {
                path: '/',
                expires: 365
            });
        });
    });
})(); //end
```

- Сохраняю значение атрибута name потому, что таких checkbox'ов пару штук на сайте.
- Итак, эти коды работают, но отключение звука срабатывает только тогда, когда происходит события click,  (это по идеи, но не совсем), нужно чтобы срабатывало по значению cookie и клик.
  Например нажал пользователь на "Отключить звук" - звук отключается и сохраняется в куки.
  Объясните ошибку в коде, пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Comment: зачем в конце `()` ?

Comment: @eicto, ошибочка, спасибо :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какая-то несостыковочка: "*... существует checkbox который при клике ...*" (id = mute) и "*таких checkbox'ов пару штук на сайте*". Будем надеятся, что несколько их, не в пределах одной страницы.

По поводу вашей задачи - я [набросал вам простой примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/CSCS8/3/), в котором не стал использовать **$.cookie** по причине того, что не вижу смысла грузить сайт лишними скриптами, когда есть готовые решения. В вашем случае - это может быть LocalStorage.

Comment: Эм.. не думаю что вы понимали о чем я. Но ваш код напомнил мне решение этой задачи, и сам решу. Благодарю за внимание!